# Identification Topology of a Cylinder

Tags: general-topology

I have a question regarding Example 3 in Chapter 3, Section 8 of Bert Mendelson's Introduction to Topology (3rd Ed. Dover Publications) (page 105).

We are looking at a unit square, $I^2\in\mathbb{R}^2$. We define the set $A$ as the left and right boundaries of the unit square (i.e., $A=\{(x,y)|(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2,(x=0,0\leq y\leq 1) \lor (x=1,0 \leq y\leq 1)\}$ ) and the unit interval $Y=[0,1]$. We also define the identification, $f:I^2\rightarrow Y$, as $f(x,y)=y$.

From this information, I identify the "inverse function", $f^{-1}:Y\rightarrow I^2$, as $f^{-1}(y)=(x,y)$, which is just a horizontal line for each $y$. And we have the topological space, $I^2\cup_fY=\left((I^2-A)\cup Y,\mathcal{T}\right)$.

The topology, $\mathcal{T}$, consists of all sets $U\subset Y$ such that $f^{-1}(U)\subset I^2$ is open. For any open subset of Y, $U=(a,b)$, where $0\leq a<b\leq1$, we get the set $f^{-1}(U)=[0,1]\times(a,b)$. The book states that $I^2\cup_fY$ is a cylinder, so this seems to say that the subsets of $\mathcal{T}$ are just the horizontal bands around the cylinder.

**Question 1:** The underlying set of $I^2\cup_fY$ is $\{(x,y)|0<x<1,0\leq y\leq 1\}\cup[0,1]$. How can I interpret this? I kind of see how the unit interval is the "seam" of the cylinder. It is a "set of 2D coordinates" and an interval. Is it given meaning through the topology and I have to have some insight to actually understand that it means something? Or is all the information of the cylinder contained in just this information?

**Question 2:** Why this topology? It seems to only contain information about continuity in one direction. If I take a cylinder and draw a small (can be seen from one side) circle (representing an open ball on the surface) that doesn't cross the "seam", why is this not an open set? Is it because of how I defined $f^{-1}$?

Thanks.

**Actual Notation:** the text defines $I^2$ as the "unit square in $R^2$", $A$ as $\{(x,y)|(x,y)\in R^2 \text{ and either }x=0,0\leq y \leq1\text{, or }x=1,0\leq y \leq 1 \}$. $Y=[0,1]$ and $X\cup_f Y$ is "the set $(X-A)\cup Y$ with the identification topology determined by $\varphi$ ($f$ in the example)".

[Picture of book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAQXU.jpg)

Comment: Does your statement of this problem exactly match the statement in the book? I ask because the statement is laced with set theoretical errors, so much so that I am unsure of the meaning of your questions.

Comment: @LeeMosher the text defines $I^2$ as the "unit square in $R^2$", $A$ as $\{(x,y)|(x,y)\in R^2 \text{ and either }x=0,0\leq y \leq1\text{, or }x=1,0\leq y \leq 1 \}$. $Y=[0,1]$ and $X\cup_f Y$ is "the set $(X-A)\cup Y$ with the identification topology determined by $\varphi$ ($f$ in the example)". I'll add them below the question

Comment: This part - 'I identify the "inverse function", $f^{-1}:Y\to I^2$, as $f^{-1}(y)=(x,y)$, which is just a horizontal line for each $y$.' - makes no sense. There is no $x$ defined, and If there were, then $f^{-1}(y)$ would be the single point $(x,y)$, not "a horizontal line". $f$ itself is not an invertible function. If you were attempting to define $f^{-1}$ as a function whose output was sets, then it would be $f^{-1}: Y \to \mathscr P(I^2)$, not into $I^2$ itself. But generally for non injective $f$, we do not consider $f^{-1}$ to be a function at all, but just a notation for pre-images.

Comment: The definition you give for $\cal T$ does not define a topology on $(I^2-A)\cup Y$ (why are we using both $I$ and $Y$ to mean $[0,1]$?). It appears to be just the topology of $Y$, without any open sets including elements of $I^2-A$. As the total space must be open, this is not allowed. Perhaps if you included the books exact wording of the definition of $f$ we could figure out what was really meant.

Comment: @PaulSinclair what does $\mathscr{P}(I^2)$ represent? An identification topology is defined in the text as: "Let $p:X\rightarrow Y$ be a function from a topological space $X$ onto a set $Y$. The _identification topology on_ $Y$ _determined by_ $p$ consists of those sets $U$ such that $p^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$" If $f$ is not invertible (which I agree it isn't, it is not bijective) how can the relative topology be defined and why would this be an example?

Comment: @PaulSinclair the books exact words are "If $Y$ is a single point $a^*$, then attaching $X$ to $a^*$ by the function $f:A\rightarrow a^*$ is the same as shrinking $A$ to a point." Then later after the other sets are defined as provided in my question it states "Let $Y=[0,1]$ be the unit interval. Define $f:I^2\rightarrow Y$ by $f(x,y)=y$. Then $I^2\cup_f Y$ is a cylinder formed by identifying the two vertical edges of $I^2$." (end of example and end of section)

Comment: $\mathscr P(S)$ is the power set, of set of all subsets, of the set $S$: $$\mathscr P(S) := \{ U\mid U \subseteq S\}$$. For any map $f : A \to B$, and $C \subseteq B$, the notation $f^{-1}(C) ;= \{ x \in A\mid f(x) \in C\}$. $f^{-1}$ is not a function here, just part of a notation of the pre-image of $C$ under $f$. By abuse of notation, we also sometimes denote $f^{-1}(\{p\})$ by $f^{-1}(p)$, but that is ambiguous when $f$ is an invertible function.

Comment: No, those are not the book's exact words. Those are snippets taken from the book without the necessary context to evaluate what is meant by them. The context for that quote with $a^*$ is quite evidently from a discussion of a different example than the one you are giving here, and is NOT the definition of the topology to be used in this example.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, my apologies, it is from the previous example about shrinking a subset to a point. It gives the example of shrinking the boundary of $I^2$ to a point which makes the resulting space homeomorphic to $S^2$. I don't know why they bring it up again but it is restated right before the part about making the cylinder. It restates the shrinking part, defines $I^2$ and $A$ then gives the sentence I quoted above ending the example. Any further information such as how $X\cup_fY$ is defined, I believe I've supplied above.

Comment: No you have not, and that is the problem. Instead of finding and reproducing the actual definition with full context, you've quoted bits either out of context, or perhaps partial requotes of it given in relation to a specific example, but you clearly have not given the full definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not answer to your question, since I do not have access to this textbook to see what it is saying. But there is something at least similar to what the book is talking about, which is called the "quotient topology". It works like this:

> Let $X$ be a topological space, and $\sim$ an equivalence relation on $X$. Consider the set $X/\sim$ of all equivalence classes of $X$ under $\sim$, and the projection $\pi : X \to X/\sim\ : x \mapsto [x]$. Then the collection of all sets $U \subset X/\sim$ such that $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ forms a topology on $X/\sim$, called the quotient topology.

In the case of $I^2$, we can define the equivalence $(x,y) \sim (x', y')$ if and only if either $(x,y) = (x',y')$ or if $y'=y$ and $|x-x'| = 1$. Note that in $I^2$, the last condition can only be met if $x = 0, x'=1$ or vice versa. The quotient topology in this case is indeed a cylinder. If you wrap the square around so that its right and left sides are in contact, then $\sim$ merely equates the left side point to its touching right side point, while leaving the other points alone.

---

Here is what I am guessing the book is doing. This is still only a guess, as I do not have a copy to peruse myself. But it fits certain patterns I see in what has been reproduced here.

Given a topological space $X$, a set $A \subset X$, another set $Y$ disjoint from $X$, and a surjective map $f : A \to Y$. Let $Z = (X - A) \cup Y$, and define a map $\phi : X \to Z$ by $$\phi(x) =\begin{cases}x&x \not\in A\\f(x)&x \in A\end{cases}$$

Define $\cal T$ by $$\mathcal T = \{ U \subseteq Z \mid \phi^{-1}(U)\text{ is open in }X\}$$Then $\cal T$ is a topology on $Z$. This follows since $\phi^{-1}(\emptyset) = \emptyset, \phi^{-1}(Z) = X$ and for any collection of sets ${\scr U \subset P}(Z), \bigcup_{U \in \scr U}\phi^{-1}(U) = \phi^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{U \in \scr U}U\right)$ and $\bigcap_{U \in \scr U}\phi^{-1}(U) = \phi^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{U \in \scr U}U\right)$. This is the *identification topology* being defined.

Note that we could instead define an equivalence relation on $X$ by $x \sim y$ if $x = y$ or ($x,y \in A$ and $f(x) = f(y)$). Note that $x \sim y$ if and only $\phi(x) = \phi(y)$, and thus $\phi/\sim : X/\sim \to Z : [x] \to \phi(x)$ is a bijection. Further, it isn't hard to show that $\phi/\sim$ is a homeomorphism between the quotient topology on $X/\sim$ and the identification topology on $Z$. Thus the quotient and identification topologies are just two ways of describing the exact same thing.

For the particular example here with $X = I^2, Y = I$, it only remains to properly define $f$. It is correct that $f(x,y) = y$, but note that $f$ *is only defined on $A$*, not all of $X$. Its extension $\phi : X \to Z$ does not follow that rule. Instead
$$\phi(x,y) = \begin{cases}(x,y)&0 < x < 1\\y&x=0\text{ or }x = 1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you, I believe these are the same concepts. I can also see how the requirement that $(x,y)=(x',y')$ or $y=y'$ and $|x-x'|=1$ gives the cylinder, but I don't see how this works in the book's notation or what the set $(I^2-A)\cup Y$ is since they are of different dimensions. I've attached a picture of the book in my question to help

Comment: Actually - I suspect what the book is doing is a variant of the quotient topology. Unfortunately, I don't have time to write it up right now. Basically, it is doing the same thing as in my construction, but - maybe to not have to delve into equivalence relations - they are going about it differently. I'll add it to my post in a couple hours.

Comment: I'ved added what I think your book is saying.

Comment: Thank you for the time you spent answering this question, I appreciate it